# If one radio button is checked then a function should run, but if another is checked then another function should run, but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, radio-button, checked

This code doesn't work. The group of functions inside each conditional works fine if one group or the other group is alone in the .js file

I want the name of the planet to appear (by clicking on it) in the "origen" or "destino" box depending on which option is selected.

I'm not sure if I have to declare all those variables.

```js
var document.getElementById("enter-origen");
var document.getElementById("enter-destino");
var document.getElementById("origen");
var document.getElementById("destino");

if (document.getElementById("origen").checked) {
  function mercurio() {
    document.getElementById("enter-origen").innerHTML = "Mercurio";
  }

  function venus() {
    document.getElementById("enter-origen").innerHTML = "Venus";
  }

  function tierra() {
    document.getElementById("enter-origen").innerHTML = "Tierra";
  }

  function marte() {
    document.getElementById("enter-origen").innerHTML = "Marte";
  }
} else if (document.getElementById("destino").checked) {
  function mercurio() {
    document.getElementById("enter-destino").innerHTML = "Mercurio";
  }

  function venus() {
    document.getElementById("enter-destino").innerHTML = "Venus";
  }

  function tierra() {
    document.getElementById("enter-destino").innerHTML = "Tierra";
  }

  function marte() {
    document.getElementById("enter-destino").innerHTML = "Marte";
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="sol">

  <div onclick="mercurio()" class="planeta mercurio"></div>
  <div onclick="venus()" class="planeta venus"></div>
  <div onclick="tierra()" class="planeta tierra"></div>
  <div onclick="marte()" class="planeta marte"></div>
</div>


<div id="panel">

  <label><input type="radio" id="origen" name="origen-destino" style= "margin:8% 0 0 5%;"><h3 style="margin: -3vh 0 0 3.5vw; cursor: pointer;">Origen</h3></label>

  <div class="display">
    <p id="enter-origen" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0.2vh;">seleccione el planeta de origen</p>
  </div>

  <label><input type="radio" id="destino" name="origen-destino" style= "position: absolute; margin:38% 0 0 5%;"><h3 style="margin: 36% 0 0 3.5vw; cursor: pointer;">Destino</h3></label>

  <div class="display">
    <p id="enter-destino" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0.2vh;">seleccione el planeta de destino</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: The `if` statement is running when the page loads, not after the user checks one of the buttons.

Comment: `var document.getElementById("enter-origen");` is invalid syntax. You're missing the variable being declared.

Comment: Just define all your functions once, and put `if` statements in them that determines where to show the result.

Comment: you need to decide when you want to check if the user has checked the input. Maybe on click of some other button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create multiple functions with the names of the planets. Planets are data.

None of the radio buttons in the question are checked, so I added `checked` to the first radio button, however this is not strictly necessary.

One simple `handleClick(event)` function is enough to handle the click.

I used an eventListener on the `sol` `div` to listen for the `click` event and I then extracted the `textContent` from the clicked `div` and copied that to the `textContent` of the appropriate `<p>` element.

```js
const solDiv = document.querySelector(".sol");

solDiv.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
  if (document.getElementById("origen").checked) {
    document.getElementById("enter-origen").textContent = event.target.textContent;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("destino").checked) {
    document.getElementById("enter-destino").textContent = event.target.textContent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sol">
  <div>Mercurio</div>
  <div>Venus</div>
  <div>Tierra</div>
  <div>Marte</div>
</div>

<div id="panel">
  <input type="radio" id="origen" name="origen-destino" checked>Origen
  <p id="enter-origen">seleccione el planeta de origen</p>
  <input type="radio" id="destino" name="origen-destino">Destino
  <p id="enter-destino">seleccione el planeta de destino</p>
</div>
```